# Ambiguous argument is not working in df['datetime'].dt.tz_localize('America/Los_Angeles', ambiguous ='NaT') for date that spans DST change

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, timezone

I am trying to convert my datetime column of my pandas DataFrame to the timezone 'America/Los_Angeles' on a date where there is a switch from **standard time** to **daylight savings time**. It was my understanding that to get pandas to accept any ambiguous times generated due to this switch, it is possible to use the ambiguous argument. My first attempt was using ambiguous = 'NaT', but I tried other arguments as well.

I am getting the pytz.exceptions.NonExistentTimeError: 2019-03-10 02:00:00 regardless. Could someone please help? I am thinking I am missing something simple/obvious.

```
import pandas as pd

# Make datetime table
date = pd.DataFrame(['2019-03-10']*24).rename(columns={0: 'date'})
hours = pd.DataFrame(list(range(0, 24))).rename(columns={0: 'hb'})
df = pd.concat([date, hours], axis=1)
df['datetime'] = df['date'] + ' ' + df['hb'].astype('str') + ':00:00'

# Convert to to datetime and try to convert to timezone
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])
df['test'] = df['datetime'].dt.tz_localize('America/Los_Angeles', ambiguous='NaT')
```

Comment: looking at your example data, this is pretty similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62621797/parse-time-zone-and-convert-to-daylight-saving-time). if your data contains DST changes, there should e.g. be no '2019-03-10 2:00:00'. if it does not, it's basically UTC-8 (PST) and you could apply the approach I describe [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62626202/10197418).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2019-03-10 02:00:00 'America/Los_Angeles' is *not* ambiguous.  It never existed at all.  But no worries, [pandas.Series.tz_localize](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.tz_localize.html) can deal with that case too:

nonexistent : *str*, *default* *‘raise’*

A nonexistent time does not exist in a particular timezone where clocks moved forward due to DST. Valid values are:

- ‘shift_forward’ will shift the nonexistent time forward to the closest existing time
- ‘shift_backward’ will shift the nonexistent time backward to the closest existing time
- ‘NaT’ will return NaT where there are nonexistent times
- timedelta objects will shift nonexistent times by the timedelta
- ‘raise’ will raise an NonExistentTimeError if there are nonexistent times.